# number of connected nodes to specific nodes in a path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query (below). 
It works but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to write this.

Based on a given starting node, the query tries to:

1. Find the following pattern/motif: `(inputko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko2:ko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko3:ko)`.
2. Foreach the motifs/patterns found, find connected nodes with labels `contigs`,  for the following nodes in the pattern: [`inputko`, `ko2`, `ko3`].
3. A summary of the 3 nodes and their connected contigs, ie. the name property `.ko` of the 3 nodes and the number of connected `:contig` nodes in each of the  `(inputko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko2:ko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko3:ko)` motifs that were found.

   ```
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | KO1         | KO1count | KO2         | KO2count | KO3         | KO3count |
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | "ko:K00001" | 102      | "ko:K14029" | 512      | "ko:K03736" | 15       |
   | "ko:K00001" | 102      | "ko:K00128" | 792      | "ko:K12972" | 7        |
   | "ko:K00001" | 102      | "ko:K00128" | 396      | "ko:K01624" | 265      |
   | "ko:K00001" | 102      | "ko:K03735" | 448      | "ko:K00138" | 33       |
   | "ko:K00001" | 102      | "ko:K14029" | 512      | "ko:K15228" | 24       |
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   ```

I'm puzzled for the syntax to operate on each match. 
From the documentation the `foreach` clause doesn't seem to be what I need. 
Any ideas guys?

> The FOREACH clause is used to update data within a collection, whether
>   components of a path, or result of aggregation.
>
> Collections and paths are key concepts in Cypher. To use them for
>   updating data, you can use the FOREACH construct. It allows you to do
>   updating commands on elements in a collection — a path, or a
>   collection created by aggregation.

```
START 
    inputko=node:koid('ko:\"ko:K00001\"') 
MATCH
    (inputko)--(c1:contigs)
WITH
    count(c1) as KO1count, inputko
MATCH
    (inputko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko2:ko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko3:ko)
WITH
    inputko.ko as KO1,
    KO1count,
    ko2,
    ko3
MATCH
    (ko2)--(c2:contigs)
WITH
    KO1,
    KO1count,
    ko2.ko as KO2,
    count(c2) as KO2count,
    ko3
MATCH
    (ko3)--(c3:contigs)
RETURN 
    KO1,
    KO1count,
    KO2,
    KO2count,
    ko3.ko     AS KO3,
    count(c3)  AS KO3count
LIMIT
    5;
```

realised that i have to place distinct for in `count(distinct cX)` to get a accurate count. Do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how *elegant* this is but I think it does give you some notion about how you could extend your query for `n` ko nodes in a path and still return the data as you have laid it out below.  It should also demonstrate the power of combining the `with` directive and collections.

```
// match the ko/cpd node paths starting with K00001
match p=(ko1:ko {name:'K00001' } )-->(:cpd)-->(ko2:ko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko3:ko)

// remove the cpd nodes from each path and name the collection row
with collect([n in nodes(p) where labels(n)[0] = 'ko' | n]) as row

// create a range for the number of rows and number of ko nodes per row
with row
, range(0, length(row)-1, 1) as idx
, range(0, 2, 1) as idx2

// iterate over each row and node in the order it was collected
unwind idx as i
unwind idx2 as j
with i, j, row[i][j] as ko_n

// find all of the contigs nodes atttached to each ko node
match ko_n--(:contigs)

// group the ko node data together in a collection preserving the order and the count
with i, [j, ko_n.name, count(*)] as ko_set
order by i, ko_set[0]

// re-collect the ko node sets as ko rows
with i, collect(ko_set) as ko_row
order by i

//return the original paths in the ko node order with the counts
return reduce( ko_str = "", ko in ko_row | 
  case 
    when ko_str = "" then ko_str + ko[1] + ", " + ko[2]
    else ko_str + ", " + ko[1] + ", " + ko[2]
  end) as `KO-Contigs Counts`
```

The `foreach` directive in cypher is strictly for mutating data.  For instance , you could use one query to collect the `contigs` counts per `ko` node.

This is a bit convoluted and you would never update the number of `contigs` on a `ko` node like this but it illustrates the use of `foreach` in cypher.

```
match (ko:ko)-->(:contigs) 
with ko,count(*) as ct
with collect(ko) as ko_nodes, collect(ct) as ko_counts
with ko_nodes, ko_counts, range(0,length(ko_nodes)-1, 1) as idx
foreach ( i in idx | 
      set (ko_nodes[i]).num_contigs = ko_counts[i]  )
```

A simpler way to perform the above update task on each `ko` node would be to do something like this...

```
match (ko:ko)-->(:contigs) 
with ko, count(*) as ct
set ko.num_contigs = ct
```

If you were to carry teh number of contigs on each ko node then you could perform a query like this to return the number of

```
// match all the paths starting with K00001
match p=(ko1:ko {name:'K00001' } )-->(:cpd)-->(ko2:ko)-->(:cpd)-->(ko3:ko)
// build a csv line per path
return reduce( ko_str = "", ko in nodes(p) | ko_str +
    // using just the ko nodes in the path
    // exclude the cpd nodes
    case 
        when labels(ko)[0] = "ko" then ko.name + ", " + toString(ko.num_contigs) + ", "
        else ""
    end
) as `KO-Contigs Counts`
```

Comment: agree with you on this. 

"If you were to carry teh number of contigs on each ko node then you could perform a query like this to return the number kos"

perhaps all update the KO nodes to store this information! it'll make the query much fast too